# How to calculate result based on adjacent rows meet some conditions

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I have a big database and want to do some complex query. Here's a demo table:

```
id   time   value
0     0001   3333  
1     1111   valueA
2     1112   6666
3     1113   valueB
4     8888   4444
```

I want to get averge of all `valueA` and avarage of all `valueB`. `valueA` and `valueB` meet following conditions:
`time` of `valueA` and `time` of `valueB` are near, eg, their difference is below 2, and row count between valueA and valueB is at least 3(including row `valueA` and row `valueB`).

Is there any convenient method to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that the true representation of time, 1111 etc?

Comment: It's unix timestamp value, and above question is an example.

Comment: I don't really understand what happens when there are multiple `valueA` values in the `value` column.  Also, what are you taking the average of?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of your need. With a little sample of what you have in input of your problem **AND** what you should have in output, maybe it will be more clearer.

Nonetheless, maybe this code can put you on the way.

```
with cte_order as
(
    select 
        *
        , row_number() over (order by t1.id)
    from test t1
)
select avg(t1.value), avg(t2.value)
from cte_order t1
    inner join cte_order t2 on t1.time between t2.time - 2 and t2.time + 2
where t1.id <> t2.id
    and abs(t1.row_number - t2.row_number) >= 3;
```